# "Hypothesis" and "theory"

Tags: differences, nouns

My basic knowledge of these two words is that they both mean the same thing. So why are they used differently, and what is their difference in meaning?

Comment: While in common vernacular today, "hypothesis" and "theory" often are used to refer to the same or very similar concepts, they actually have very different meanings - especially in the scientific community.  Hopefully, someone can come in and explain the difference between "hypothesis", "theory", and "law" from a scientific standpoint.

Comment: See also [this related question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7573/use-of-the-word-theory-in-string-theory-m-theory-etc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's get some standard definitions in here.

**hypothesis:**

> A proposal intended to explain certain facts or observations; a tentative insight into the natural world; a concept that is not yet verified but that if true would explain certain facts or phenomena.
>
> A scientific hypothesis that survives experimental testing becomes a scientific theory.

**theory:**

> A well-substantiated explanation of some aspect of the natural world; an organized system of accepted knowledge that applies in a variety of circumstances to explain a specific set of phenomena.
>
> Theories can incorporate facts and laws and tested hypotheses.

All from [wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn).

Comment: @Mathew both of them are loan - words from Greek Language. If you may analysed them then you will come to the same conclusion. Thus your approach is the most accurate of all , according to my opinion. Also the word "phenomena" is a loan - word

Answer (score 3):

A hypothesis is a testable prediction.

A theory is a tested, and usually widely accepted, hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is mainly related to their usage in american-english. Originally, these two words have very different meanings.

A *hypothesis* is an assumption made for the sake of argument.

*Theory* is the analysis of a set of facts in their relation to one another used to draw a conclusion or an explanation of some phenomenon. A theory may use a number of hypothesis to draw one, or more, conclusions.

Unfortunately, people often say "it's just a theory" almost as if *theory* was an assumption about something. Nonetheless, you can see the difference from the definitions above.

Answer (score 1):

A *hypothesis* is something expected to be true, but not yet proved (Synonyms: presumption, assumption, conjecture). For example:

- **The Continuum Hypothesis:** There are more real numbers than integers.
- **The Collatz Conjecture:** If a number is even, find *n/2*; if it is odd, find *3n + 1*. Upon repeating, one will reach the number *1* eventually.

However, a theory is a proposition which is most likely to be true, and is derived from other true statements (theorems). They may also be analyses of facts. For example:

- **Game theory:** A topic in economics based on real-life strategies.
- **Set theory:** A branch of mathematics focusing on sets, both in real life and theoretical.

Answer (score 0):

Hypothesis is a single statement regarding relationship between variables that can be tested by observation. Hypotheses are usually formulated to support or deny theories. Usually,  several hypotheses on a fact, if scientifically proven, become a theory.

A theory, on the other hand, is a systematic set of generalization that explains some phenomenal linking variables in order to come up with principles that are internally consistent. It should be noted that a theory is only accepted after successful researches on  a certain formulation about a fact are done while a hypothesis is just a mere formulation of a fact.